# WebDriver C# how do i capture img src - verify image is present

Tags: c#, image, webdriver

I am trying to FindElement in Webdriver C# of an image.  I have tried using the *xpath* shown below.

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/form/div[7]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a/img"));
```

But this one is not working, shows invalid selector, unable to locate element in NUnit.

What syntax can I use to use the img src attribute?

In **Firebug** the **src is**

```
img src="/Images/logos/test-logo_185x63.png" alt="test"/
```

Thanks,

Comment: is it all about Selenium Web Driver?

Comment: Please post more surrounding HTML. What do you want to do? Get the image and do what with it? Just verify it's there? Verify it's visible? Verify it's got some certain attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your XPath to;

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form/div[7]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a/img"));
```

However, I woudl point out that this looks like quite a brittle XPath, so if you provided the entire HTML, I could recommend a better one.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you want to use the src-attribute to locate the image. So you could locate it using a css-Selector, `By.CssSelector("img[src=/Images/logos/test-logo_185x63.png]")` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use the xpath with the features of the element:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[contains(@src,'test-logo_185x63.png') and contains(@alt,'test')]"));
```